# Have US state and territory abbreviations and want to convert to full name

Tags: r

abbr2state (a function from the openintro library) doesn't work since it doesn't work on US territories it seems. What libraries can I use, etc.?

I.E.

```
   Have    Want
    AS      American Samoa 
    GU      Guam 
    ...     ...
```

If I use abbr2state it just ignores these territories.

Comment: Can you show some examples

Comment: Sure, updated question.

Comment: What is `abbr2state`? It seems like you're asking for a lookup table, but that's the sort of resource question that's off topic for SO

Comment: can you check the `maps` package

Answer (score 0):

luckly this is (like many other usefull things) already implemented in R.

```
cbind(state.abb,state.name)
```

will give you your desired output

```
     state.abb state.name  
[1,] "AL"      "Alabama"   
[2,] "AK"      "Alaska"    
[3,] "AZ"      "Arizona"   
[4,] "AR"      "Arkansas"  
[5,] "CA"      "California"
[6,] "CO"      "Colorado"
```

EDIT::

to also get the territories you can use USAboundaries package:

```
install.packages('USAboundaries')
library(USAboundaries)

#lookuptable territorys :

state_codes[state_codes$jurisdiction_type == "territory",]

#state_name                     state_abbr state_code jurisdiction_type
# <chr>                          <chr>      <chr>      <chr>            
 #1 American Samoa                 "AS"       60         territory        
 #2 Federated States of Micronesia "FM"       64         territory        
 #3 Guam                           "GU"       66         territory        
 #4 Johnson Atoll                  ""         67         territory        
 #5 Marshall Islands               "MH"       68         territory        
 #6 Northern Mariana Islands       "MP"       69         territory        
 #7 Palau                          "PW"       70         territory        
 #8 Midway Islands                 ""         71         territory        
 #9 Puerto Rico                    "PR"       72         territory
```